# Array index out of bounds Error

Tags: java

I've been having some trouble with this code I made up, in that I've been getting an `ArrayIndexOutofBounds` exception error and I have no idea what is going on. What I want my code to produce is a char array of numbers.

Here's the code:

```
public class testing {

    static int k = 2;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int[] numArr = new int[] { 15, 18, 21 };

        createChar(numArr, k);
    }

    public static char[] createChar(int numArr[], int k) {
        char[] store = new char[k - 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            int divide = numArr[i] / 4;

            int numStore = divide % 4;
            charN(numStore, store, k);
        }
        return store;
    }

    public static char[] charN(int numStore, char store[], int k) {
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            if (k == 0) {
            } else {
                store[k - 1] = (char) numStore;
                k = k - 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(store);
        return store;
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What line is the exception from? Please post a stack trace.

Answer (score 4):

As the error suggests, it is due to access outside the bounds of the array. ie. some bad index access on an array.

```
char[] store = new char[k - 1];
```

You are creating a `store` character array of size `k-1`

and passing `k` as size to `charN()`

```
charN(numStore, store, k);
```

To resolve your problem.
change store declaration as below

```
char[] store = new char[k];
```

Also, in `class Testing`, `k` must be `3`, not 2. where k is the size of the array.

```
static int k = 3;
```

When **size** of the array is k, the **indices** of array run from `0` to `k-1`

Comment: I made that change Sibrajas , but it doesn't seem to print anything. Any ideas why ? By the way , I am a beginner in Java , so please excuse my lack of know how .

Comment: Still no print . Is there a problem with the System.print line or no ?

Comment: @Sibrajas.. Your last edit is pointless. Printing a char array will print a string with the combination of character.

Answer (score 1):

For value `k = 2`, the below statement: -

```
char[] store = new char[k - 1];
```

creates an array of size `1`. So, you can only access its `0th index`.

But, further in the `charN` method, you are accessing it's `1st` index at: -

```
store[k - 1] = (char) numStore;  // Since k = 2, k - 1 = 1.
```

---

Change your array creation to: -

```
char[] store = new char[k];
```

---

Furthermore, I don't understand why you took `k = 2` on first place. May be you meant it to be used as `index`, in which case, your array creation would be of size `k + 1`. And accordingly, your for loop will iterate till `k + 1`, rather than `k`.

Also, I don't understand the role of your `charN` method. In fact, tt seems strange that first you are iterating over your array in `createChar` method, and then passing each element to `charN` method. And then there also you are iterating over the `char array`, assigning the same value to multiple index. Apart from that, you are decrementing `k` and incrementing `i` at the same time in the loop. That is really strange. And at the end, you are returning your `array` from both of your methods, but are not using the return value at all.

It's quite hard to understand what you want to do. But you should consider all the points I stated in the previous paragraph. For each step there, think of why you want to do this? Is there any alternative, which might be easy? Do, I really need to methods with 2 iteration here?

I suggest you to take a look at your design once again. The solution which I posted above might solve your `compiler error`, but there is some problem with your `logic`. You need to take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

As per your post the statement

```
char[] store = new char[k - 1];
```

results in a char array of size 1.
So in charN  method  when you try to access the

```
store[k - 1] = (char) numStore;
```

you are trying to access store[1]  as 'k' is 2 here. Which is wrong.  because with store[1] you are trying to access the second element in the array where as the array size is only 1.